# Is ために　here a wrong one?

Tags: grammar

Could someone please help with the correct answer to this N3 challenge? I thought the correct one is　ために　but apparently I'm wrong.

今度の試合に勝てる　（ために）一生けんめいがんばります。

Variants given: ために　ことに　ように　みたいに

Comment: That sentence was in an exam? The ことに part looks incorrect and unnatural.　Nonetheless, +1 for getting me curious.

Comment: Chances are I'm wrong about the correct answer. However, I've listed all variants, could you, pls, point out the one you think correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd say

> 今度の試合に勝てる**ように**一生けんめいがんばります。(potential form + ように)

or

> 今度の試合に勝**つために**一生けんめいがんばります。(dictionary form + ために)